Bluetooth doesn't work on Ubuntu 24.04
I've installed ubuntu 24.04 on my geecom A7. And I wasn't able to figure out why bluetooth is not working. Problem looks same as described here:
https://www.cnx-software.com/2024/02/24/geekom-a7-mini-pc-review-ubuntu-22-04-ubuntu-24-04-linux/
For the record, bluetooth works fine on windows (on same mini PC).

rfkill shows that Bluetooth is not blocked.

rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


bluetoothctl reports that there is no default controller.

[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available


lsmod shows

lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth            1089536  15 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth


systemcltl shows

systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-05-24 11:05:05 CST; 13min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1029 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 37566)
     Memory: 2.8M (peak: 3.1M)
        CPU: 32ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1029 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 24 11:05:05 terrasoff-A7 systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.
May 24 11:05:05 terrasoff-A7 bluetoothd[1029]: Starting SDP server
May 24 11:05:05 terrasoff-A7 bluetoothd[1029]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support csip plugin
May 24 11:05:05 terrasoff-A7 bluetoothd[1029]: profiles/audio/micp.c:micp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
May 24 11:05:05 terrasoff-A7 bluetoothd[1029]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support micp plugin
May 24 11:05:05 terrasoff-A7 bluetoothd[1029]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support vcp plugin
May 24 11:05:05 terrasoff-A7 bluetoothd[1029]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support mcp plugin
May 24 11:05:05 terrasoff-A7 bluetoothd[1029]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bass plugin
May 24 11:05:05 terrasoff-A7 bluetoothd[1029]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bap plugin
May 24 11:05:05 terrasoff-A7 bluetoothd[1029]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized


dmesg | grep -i bluetooth shows

[    6.914793] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.914815] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    6.914816] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.914819] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.914821] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.914825] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.512540] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.512545] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.512549] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.933590] Modules linked in: qrtr bnep binfmt_misc intel_rapl_msr nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_realtek amdgpu(+) edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm_amd snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi kvm snd_hda_codec irqbypass snd_hda_core mt7921e crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep amdxcp mt7921_common polyval_clmulni btusb snd_pcm drm_exec mt792x_lib polyval_generic btrtl gpu_sched snd_seq_midi mt76_connac_lib ghash_clmulni_intel btintel drm_buddy snd_seq_midi_event mt76 sha256_ssse3 btbcm drm_suballoc_helper drm_ttm_helper snd_rawmidi sha1_ssse3 btmtk ttm snd_seq mac80211 aesni_intel bluetooth drm_display_helper snd_seq_device crypto_simd snd_timer cec ecdh_generic cryptd rc_core cfg80211 snd ecc wmi_bmof rapl i2c_algo_bit input_leds joydev ccp soundcore k10temp libarc4 i2c_piix4 apple_mfi_fastcharge amd_pmc mac_hid msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore nfnetlink dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_apple hid_generic usbhid sdhci_pci
[    9.061366] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110


lsusb doesn't show my Bluetooth name:

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:3585 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. Aluminium Keyboard (ANSI)
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 05e3:0625 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.2 Hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub


hcitool dev doesn't find any bluetooth device.

/var/lib/bluetooth is empty

lspci shows


00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e8
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e9
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 19h USB4/Thunderbolt PCIe tunnel
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f7
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5021-E21 PCIe4 NVMe Controller (DRAM-less)
65:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Phoenix1 (rev c2)
65:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
65:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 19h (Model 74h) CCP/PSP 3.0 Device
65:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b9
65:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ba
65:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
65:00.7 Signal processing controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 164a
66:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
66:00.1 Signal processing controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] AMD IPU Device
67:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
67:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c0
67:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c1
67:00.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Pink Sardine USB4/Thunderbolt NHI controller #1

Any ideas how to fix it?

Just for info add results of sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth and also see if lsusb gets your bluetooth name and model otherwise find the name and model of your bluetooth and put that also in your question. Your problem may be driver, You may also use the USB of Ubuntu 24.04 and use Try Ubuntu to see if your Bluetooth work.

I've enriched the question with additional information. I also wasn't able to find a bluetooth name. Try Ubuntu from USB doesn't work with bluetooth as well. I also tried Ubuntu 23.10. And I've got same issue.

Does lspci show your bluetooth?

Sometimes the wireless/bt is hung off the sdio bus.  Check the /sys/bus/sdio/devices  or drivers .Takes a driver to handle that bus, but might be hard to find (rtl8723bs for instance) so you might just get a USB bt dongel.

"So I then diagnosed that the issue was due to the product ID not being recognised for this particular card attached to the USB bus. It actually only requires a very simple patch to the relevant module which can be installed using DKMS to get working Bluetooth." from https://liliputing.com/geekom-a7-review-this-amd-ryzen-7000u-mini-pc-hits-the-sweet-spot/

"Product ID not being recognised". Yes, sounds very relative to the problem!
"Which can be installed using DKMS to get working Bluetooth". I'd like to try it. Are there any instructions how to do it? Could you give me a hint how to start? How to get the ID and how to build/install the DKMS?

I just upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04 and ran into the exact same problem.
Found a "solution" that had me entering in terminal:
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
systemctl --user start pulseaudio

This worked for me but it does not persist between sessions. Had to add these two lines to my .xsessionrc file in my home directory to make it persist. That's not a real solution but, until a real fix is released, it has to do.

systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /etc/xdg/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service is masked.

I got error: Failed to enable unit: Unit file pulseaudio.service does not exist.

First remove the config file for PulseAudio with:
rm  -rf ~/.config/pulse/*

Then restart your machine where the PulseAudio will be reconfigured automatically giving you a dependency error. For my case, the desktop environment did not load at first. So I installed GNOME via terminal. Οnce installed, I tried to install a different environment for Ubuntu 24.04 with:
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop

This gives an error message:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-unity-desktop : Depends: pulseaudio
                        Recommends: pulseaudio-module-bluetooth but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So I installed the recommended package, pulseaudio-module-bluetooth, which worked fine. However the Bluetooth couldn't connect and hold, so I inputted the following commands to fix this:
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio

followed by:
systemctl --user start pulseaudio

Worked perfectly.

I had a similar problem. While searching for a solution, I focused my attention on the

bluetoothctl reports that there is no default controller.

I've checked if Bluetooth firmware is installed by the command:
ls /lib/firmware/brcm

There should be a file BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd or similar to that.
I didn't have it. Then that file was downloaded and copied to /lib/firmware/brcm from https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware
In my case:
sudo cp BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/

The next step is restarting the Bluetooth service btusb
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth

That was useful for me.
For testing run:
bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power on

Hope it will be useful.

I have the same issue as the main question, I have tried everything, it seems to be an issue with MT7921e chipset and its firmware, the weired thing is that this chipset controls both wifi and bluetooth, and wifi workd fine, for sure your situation is the same

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
